# What express route can I use for any file in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a directory of `PDF` files that I only want authorized users to access. Currently, the issue is when I navigate to the URL that contains a given file in the folder the get callback isn't running. For example, I expect when I go to `localhost:3000/Buyer_templates/file.pdf` it will run the callback in the get. Currently, it allows me to view the pdf and the callback is not executed.

```
app.get('/Buyer_templates/*', (req,res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

The above code works if the url isn't a file (e.g `/Buyer_templates/blahblahblah`)

However, when I put in a file name (e.g. `Buyer_templates/file.pdf`) the callback isn't activated.

I also tried these paths in the get

```
/Buyer_templates/*.*

/Buyer_templates/(.*)
```

The issue is the callback isn't being executed. How can I make it so when I put in any `PDF` file name within the URL the callback is run?

Comment: Do you have a static route configured?

Comment: @James I am using this `app.use( express.static(__dirname));`  (sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: if you use static routes, your pdf files will be available to everyone just like css files or images. Use a custom route, check if the user has credentials, and only then serve the static file. I did something like this with mp4 videos, chech it https://jsfiddle.net/2uqtagn5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure [`static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) route in Express, any files from within the hierarchy from the root folder are served automatically. For example, if I had a folder structure like so:

```
root
- public
-- css
-- js
-- img
```

And my server looked like

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`REQUEST LOGGED: ${req.url}`);
  return next();
});
...
```

When I access any file URL that resides within that static root e.g.

```
/css/somefile.css
/js/somefile.js
/img/somefile.jpg
```

Then you would notice that the request never hits the `console.log`, that's because Express understands that these are a. files and b. reside within the static directory, and thus don't require any further processing (hence why you notice if you try non-file URLs they *do* process further).

In terms of adding some form of authorization to static files, there are a couple of ways you can do it e.g.

- exclude this particular folder from the static route and process the authorization that you would do in any other route

> ```
> app.get('/Buyer_templates/*', (req, res, next) => 
>   if (/* some authorization check */) {
>     return res.sendFile('...');
>   } else {
>     return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
>   }
> });
> ```

- add your authorization middleware *before* you setup the static route (although it would mean a bit more work determining which URLs to check etc.)

> ```
> app.use((req, res, next) => {
>   if (req.path.startsWith('/Buyer_templates')) {
>     return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
>   }
>   return next();
> })
> app.use(express.static(__dirname));
> ```

The examples above are just simplistic for demonstration, but they should give you the desired effect. Also, worth pointing out that `express.static(__dirname)` isn't advisable as it would make *all* files accessible from the root of your app, which would include any code you may have hosted on the server. Be more specific i.e. `express.static('Buyer_templates')`